# Populate IEnumerable using custom 'AsJson' extension method for model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, model, extension-methods

I'm looking to create a custom concept that allows model binding for any IEnumerable from Json data in an MVC view.  My solution so far requires a wrapper;

```
public interface IEnumerableWithJson<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
    string AsJson { get; set; }
}

public class EnumerableWithJson<T> : IEnumerableWithJson<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }

    public string AsJson
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
        }
        set
        {
            Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view a hidden field to bind to MyIEnumerable, which is of type `IEnumerableWithJson<T>` (I'm using knockout, but any Json formatted data would work);

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind='value: ko.toJSON(jsonData)' name="MyIEnumerable.AsJson"/>
```

This works great, however it requires all IEnumerable's to use my custom interface, and there's an extra superfluous layer.

Ideally (for context), I'd like my hidden field to look the same, but where MyIEnumerable is of type `IEnumerable<T>`.

Is there a way to extend IEnumerable to include an 'AsJson' method, then use that in an MVC view to bind to IEnumerables in the controller?  Or is there a better way to do this I've not thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I do this is by using a customised model binder and associated attribute:

```
public sealed class BindFromJsonAttribute : Attribute
{ }

public class BindFromJsonModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<Attribute>().Any(x => (x is BindFromJsonAttribute)))
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
        }

        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

To use this you can decorate your model as necessary, for example:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(BindFromJsonModelBinder))]
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [BindFromJson]
    public IEnumerable<MyChildModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You can now post back a form with a mixture of standard fields and fields containing Json.  The model binder will deserialize the fields containing Json where you have specified.

For example (using the model defined above), when posting back the following form:

```
using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
    @Html.Hidden("Items", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Items))
    <button type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

to the following `ActionResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel myModel)
{
    //myModel.Items will be populated from json
    return View();
}
```

`myModel.Items` will be populated from the Json that was sent in the hidden field.